# Passing comboBox to a different Form

Tags: c#, forms, combobox

Trying for a while to pass data from comboBox in my Main Form to a comboBox located  in a different form and even though I went through the other similar/same threads I can't figure out why it doesn't want to be displayed in the different form.

Main Form:

```
    public static ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();


    private void ComboTransfer()
    {
        string sql = "SELECT [Department] FROM [employeeTable]";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(dr[0]);
        }
        cb = comboBox1;
        Department_wise_Employee_Details dep = new Department_wise_Employee_Details(cb);
    }
```

Department_wise_Employee_Details Form:

```
public partial class Department_wise_Employee_Details : Form
{
    public Department_wise_Employee_Details()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Department_wise_Employee_Details(ComboBox cb)
    {
        comboBox1 = cb;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the constructors for the other form I am assuming that what you have in the Details form is just one constructor do you have an empty constructor as well also do you have a comboBox1 object inside of the details form..? where are you calling the `Department_wise_Employee_Details.Show()` does the form even show up..? please show the full class definition of the 2nd form

Comment: With the object you mean the control inserted to the Form? If yes then it is there. The Show method is called in the other form. Basically from Main form you go to Welcome Form / Homepage and there is called the Show method for the form Department_wise_Employee_Details also the form you wanted I've just fully copied.

Comment: Instead of trying to pass a whole control I suggest to load a DataTable, and then pass the same datatable to the second form

Answer (score 1):

Passing the global static `cb` to your second form could work but you need to read the items of this passed combo and add one by one the the combobox defined inside the second form.

If you simply reassign the second combo to use the global one you need also to add that one to the controls collection of the second form (and I am not sure what will be the side effects of using a static control here).

Perhaps the best method is to **pass the shared data** and let the Form engine do its usual work with controls. In this case you load a `DataTable` with the data to be shared and use it to set the datasource property of the two combos.

For example

```
private void ComboTransfer()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string sql = "SELECT [Department] FROM [employeeTable]";
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    using(SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        dt.Load(dr);
    }
    comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
    Department_wise_Employee_Details dep = 
                 new Department_wise_Employee_Details(dt);
}

....


public partial class Department_wise_Employee_Details : Form
{
    ....
    public Department_wise_Employee_Details(DataTable dt)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: Absolutely agree with all what you just wrote Steve..but still after all of that the comboBox data from the Main Form doesn't get displayed in the other one.

Answer (score 0):

In such scenarios always pass the data to the new form not the controls. ComboBox can be easily binded with data sources like DataTable, List etc.